# Socket programming read() function error why?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, network-programming, client-server

I have a question about socket programming in c language on linux.

When my client program is connected to server program, Sometimes unidentified error appears in read() function.

I am not certain what situation causes this problem.

It looks like infinite loop. Program stopped on that place and anything happens.

Even when I write my code like this

```
int message = 1;

while(message > 0){
    printf("READ ERROR");
    message = read(sockfd, recvBuff, sizeof(recvBuff));
}
```

It prints anything!!

As I think, if there is an error, READ ERROR should be printed at least one time.

Why this situation happens??

Comment: I don't understand your code.  Your while() drops out 'cos message is not greater than 1 and, besides, why is receiving just one char considered bad?

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. **use the debugger `gdb`** (and perhaps also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)

Comment: Sorry, that was mistake, I edited while condition to message > 0

Answer (score 2):

Read carefully [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), and [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

As [Jesferman answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44218702/841108) your `while` should be `while(message>0)`. I assume you did correct that.

On EOF (that is when the remote host closed or [shutdown(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) the socket), `read` can return 0.

`read` can also fail (returning -1), then check [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) probably by using [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html).

And `read` can block if there is nothing to read. You may want to use [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) before `read`-ing.

Also, you forgot to end your `printf` format with `\n` (or to call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)...) so it is likely that the `READ ERROR` is sitting in `stdout`'s buffer. Remember that `<stdio.h>` is buffered IO. See also [setvbuf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html).

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- `read()` returned 1 because exactly one character was available (original code)
- it returned zero, meaning the peer has disconnected
- it returned -1, meaning an error, whose value is available in `errno` and can be printed by `perror()`.

Only one of these three conditions is an error, and which error it was is no mystery.

> As I think, if there is an error, READ ERROR should be printed at least one time.

No. The loop is entered only if something was read, in which case there *wasn't* a read error. So printing the message inside the loop doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `while` condition. Your code is no entering inside because message is not greater than 1, but exactly 1, so the condition is not true and never enters in the while loop